# Bending a mesh created from SVG

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I have a mesh that was created from an SVG file (using InkScape) and I want to bend it around a smooth curved wall. I am using a lattice but there's not enough vertical cuts and I don't know how to create them in this instance, so I end up with a deformed mesh. Can anyone help? Thanks

[image: The object and the wall]
[image: Edit mode]
[image: What I end up with]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with imported SVGs is, that the topology is awful. In your second image, you can see how the triangles are arranged. Now, blender can only deform meshes at vertices, edges will always stay straight. That's why you get the bad result with bending.

Probably, it would help to remesh your imported part before bending, using the modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html
Quite likely, the "sharp" setting should give a useful result. You may wish to experiment with the settings a little, especially the "octree depth".

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, it actually had a lot more unnecessary edges that I had already dissolved. But the Remesh modifier did exactly what I needed, thanks again!